# Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in /xxx/base_facebook.php on line 886

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, iptables

I am getting the above error when I am using Facebook PHP-SDK to implement FB login for my website. I have tried changing the iptables to open ports 80 and 443. Currently my iptables reads like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports www,https       state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook recently started accepting requests to the Graph API servers over IPV6.

Check your system's IPV6 interface is correctly configured, and disable it if it isn't.

This has been the cause of 2/3rds of people asking about 'couldn't connect to host' errors lately.

Comment: Then this is probably a server configuration problem on your side and not really in scope for stackoverflow - maybe try  serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks lgy. I will have a look.